# SOLR multicore shared configuration

Tags: configuration, solr

I'm using multiple cores in SOLR to enable offline population of indices (and then using SWAP to swap out the active core). I want to use the same solrconfig.xml file for both cores - can someone tell me where I should put this so it can be picked up by SOLR?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think I solved it... simply by specifying the *same* instanceDir (but different dataDir) in the  confiugation in solr.xml